# Configure Ghostscript to work with "MT Extra" font

Tags: ghostscript, eps

I'm using MathType to write mathematical expressions, which uses "MT Extra" font to do some extra symbols. MathType saves the equation in a .eps format, which I want to add to a Scribus document as an image.
Exporting to .pdf with "embed .eps files" option doesn't show the extra symbols written with the MT Extra font.  Since Scribus works with Ghostscript, I believe I have to configure ghostscript to use MT Extra font.  Am I right?  How can I do that?
ThankYou for your time.

Thank you for your answer, @KenS. I'm using Windows. The font is embed, but I really can't understand (reading the ghostscript documentation) how to use the -I switch on ghostscript command line to include the font path. When I use GSView I can configure it in "Advanced configure" (using -sFONTPATH=c:\windows\fonts), and the .eps looks ok, but it doesn't change the behaviour of ghostscript when I insert the .eps into Scribus (and ghostscript is configured to be the ps interpreter). I don't know how to tell directly to ghostscript to include the fontpath. I'm sorry to ask you again, @KenS, and thank you again for your time.

Comment: -sFONTPATH is the same for GS as it is for GSView, its just an additional GS switch you can add to GSView. You can find more information on these in ghostpdl/gs/doc/Use.htm, section 8.2 Font Lookup

Answer (score 0):

If the font is embedded in the EPS file, then you don't need to do anything. If they are not then you should get a warning from Ghostscript that a font can't be found and a substitute is being used. If you get that warning then you need to add the font, otherwise you don't. Its poor practice not to embed fconts though.

Adding fonts to Ghostscript is documented in ghostpdl/gs/doc/Fonts.htm See Section 7 in particular.

Assuming you are on Linux you may, or may not, have a ROM file system, depending on how your distribution has chosen to package Ghostscript. If you are using a ROM file system then you will I think need to use the -I switch to include different font paths (again there is documentation on this). If you are not using a ROM file system, or the package already includes fonts on disk then its only necessary to follow the steps described in the documentation.